# Vundle directory automatically copied to dotfiles directory with weird permissions

Tags: macos, git, dotfiles

I just installed [mathiasbynens dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) (only the bootstrap scripts, not os x default, not that it matters). The bootstrap script copies all the files to ~ folder (not symlink, copy). Anyways, I have barely touched them, so it's nothing that I did.

Now, when I cloned vundle with

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim)
```

for some reason the files got copied to ~/dotfiles/.vim/bundle too (dotfiles is the folder where I installed mathiasbynens dotfiles). I got the following from ls -l:

In ~/.vim/bundle

```
drwxr-xr-x  11 mattiasahlsen  staff  374 Aug 14 20:14 Vundle.vim
```

In ~/dotfiles/.vim/bundle

```
drw-r--r--@ 11 root  staff  374 Aug 14 20:22 Vundle.vim
```

So the other one is created 8 minutes later. I also constantly get this warning when I'm in the dotfiles folder:

```
warning: unable to access '.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/.gitignore': Permission denied
```

I also can't enter Vundle.vim directory in dotfiles (not even with sudo).

This doesn't make much sense to me, It says nothing about it in the github page and I find nothing googling. Please help!